# My hard drive indicates a SMART trip, should I toss it or does it still have purpose?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Seriousness of a “Smart” disk error. How long will it last?](https://superuser.com/questions/82636/seriousness-of-a-smart-disk-error-how-long-will-it-last)

My hard drive has a SMART trip, and while I have a rough understanding of this, I don't know the severity degree.  I've backed up the drive and bought it's replacement, so no need to worry there.

My question simply comes down to this: is the hard drive now utterly useless and should just be tossed, or can I do something with it to make it useful?  Are there any uses of a drive that has SMART tripped?  I just hate to waste it if it still has purpose.

Thank you!

Comment: Run the HDD manufacturer's utility and select the long/thorough test. See what it has to say about the drive's health. You can then try and do a complete zero fill and see if the drive works, then use it to hold unimportant data for as long as it lasts.

Comment: specifically what SMART metric has exceeded its threshold? they are not all equally serious, ranging from trivial to outright disastrous. I've often used SpeedFan in windows or gnome-disk-utility in ubuntu to read SMART data

Comment: Thanks for that tip @FrankThomas, I took a look at it using SpeedFan and found a surprisingly long list of issues... but they all seem related to the same blocking issues.  I guess I need a tool to do repairs on the drive, but I get the feeling it's probably not worth it from what I'm reading.  Anyway, that was an excellent tip, thank you!